# Vue & Vuex - not sorting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, vuejs2, vuex

I am using Vuex for storing my **Lessons** array which has objects of lessons. Everything is displayed as I want to and working perfectly. Now I need to do sorting. I wrote this code:

```
sortSubj() {
  this.$store.state.Lessons.Title.sort(function (a, b) {
    let titleA = a.Title.toUpperCase()
    let titleB = b.Title.toUpperCase()
     if (titleA < titleB) {
       return -1
     }
     if (titleA > titleB) {
       return 1
     }
  })
},
```

Im expecting this to sort my array based on the Title when pressing the button.

```
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="Subject" autocomplete="off" checked @click="sortSubj"> Subject
        </label>
```

But unfortunately nothing happens. Im adding a picture how code looks for displaying lessons with v-for cycle. [image: Code for displaying lessons]
Whats wrong? why is it doing nothing? I get no errors as well. Does it has to be in the same cycle or what? Im really stuck with this, this is my first time using Vuex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not mutate the state like you did, try to commit a mutation or dispatch an action to sort the state in your store :

```
this.$store.commit('SORT_LESSONS_BY_TITLE')
```

store :

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    Lessons:{[]}
  },
  mutations: {
    SORT_LESSONS_BY_TITLE(state) {
      state.Lessons.sort(function (a, b) {
    let titleA = a.Title.toUpperCase()
    let titleB = b.Title.toUpperCase()
     if (titleA < titleB) {
       return -1
     }
     if (titleA > titleB) {
       return 1
     }
  })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Just needed to change from: state.Lessons.Title.sort....
to: state.Lessons.sort....